# Postfix cannot send any mail to internal domain

Tags: postfix

wasted too much time but could not find the problem. Postfix send any email to everywhere except not to my own domain.

I am getting 550-Unrouteable address 550 Sender verify failed (in reply to RCPT TO command)) error.

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
#myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination =
#relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4

smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
header_size_limit = 4096000

relayhost =
myorigin = /etc/mailname
```

I added many things to mydestination for example localhost, localhost.$mydomain and others but still same

here is the mail.log

```
Jul 26 22:46:45 mydomain postfix/postfix-script[15524]: stopping the Postfix mail system
Jul 26 22:46:45 mydomain postfix/master[14952]: terminating on signal 15
Jul 26 22:46:45 mydomain postfix/postfix-script[15660]: warning: symlink leaves directory: /etc/postfix/./makedefs.out
Jul 26 22:46:45 mydomain postfix/postfix-script[15835]: starting the Postfix mail system
Jul 26 22:46:45 mydomain postfix/master[15837]: daemon started -- version 3.4.13, configuration /etc/postfix
Jul 26 22:47:03 mydomain postfix/pickup[15839]: 658DD400BC: uid=0 from=<root@mydomain.com>
Jul 26 22:47:03 mydomain postfix/cleanup[15878]: 658DD400BC: message-id=<20210726204703.658DD400BC@mydomain.com>
Jul 26 22:47:03 mydomain postfix/qmgr[15840]: 658DD400BC: from=<root@mydomain.com>, size=399, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 26 22:47:03 mydomain postfix/smtp[15883]: 658DD400BC: to=<order@mydomain.com>, relay=lx31.hoststar.hosting[168.119.43.209]:25, delay=0.51, delays=0.14/0.13/0.19/0.05, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host lx31.blabla.hosting[168.119.43.209] said: 550-Verification failed for <root@mydomain.com> 550-Unrouteable address 550 Sender verify failed (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Jul 26 22:47:03 mydomain postfix/cleanup[15878]: CCEE1400C0: message-id=<20210726204703.CCEE1400C0@mydomain.com>
Jul 26 22:47:03 mydomain postfix/qmgr[15840]: CCEE1400C0: from=<>, size=2634, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jul 26 22:47:03 mydomain postfix/bounce[15885]: 658DD400BC: sender non-delivery notification: CCEE1400C0
Jul 26 22:47:03 mydomain postfix/qmgr[15840]: 658DD400BC: removed
Jul 26 22:47:04 mydomain postfix/smtp[15883]: CCEE1400C0: to=<root@mydomain.com>, relay=lx31.hoststar.hosting[111.111.4113.209]:25, delay=1.1, delays=0/0.01/0.13/1, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host lx31.blabla.hosting[111.111.11.209] said: 550 Unrouteable address (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Jul 26 22:47:04 mydomain postfix/qmgr[15840]: CCEE1400C0: removed
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recipient is rejecting the mail you sent because the sender email address cannot be verified as real.

```
Jul 26 22:47:03 mydomain postfix/smtp[15883]: 658DD400BC: to=<order@mydomain.com>, relay=lx31.hoststar.hosting[168.119.43.209]:25, delay=0.51, delays=0.14/0.13/0.19/0.05, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host lx31.blabla.hosting[168.119.43.209] said: 550-Verification failed for <root@mydomain.com> 550-Unrouteable address 550 Sender verify failed (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

To send email to this recipient, use a real email address as the sender.